# Why the maxmin divide and conquer implementation is slower than the others maxmin algorithms?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, code-analysis

I'm comparing the complexity about the implementation of the maxmin algorithm and I have implemented in two ways: the brute force way and the divide and conquer way. After I tested both two algorithms for ten input of elements between 1000000 and 10000000. Follow below the algorithms:

The brute force implementation below:

```
def maxmin1(vetor):
    max,min = vetor[0],vetor[0];
    for elem in vetor[1:]:
        if elem > max:
            max = elem
        if elem < min:
            min = elem
    return (min,max)
```

and divide and conquer implementation below:

```
def maxmin4(vetor,inicio,fim):
    if ((fim - inicio) == 1):
        return (vetor[inicio], vetor[inicio])
    elif ((fim - inicio) == 2):
        if( vetor[inicio] < vetor[inicio+1]):
            return (vetor[inicio], vetor[inicio+1])
        else:
            return (vetor[inicio+1], vetor[inicio])
    else:
        (min_left,max_left) = maxmin4(vetor,inicio,(fim-inicio)/2 + inicio)
        (min_right,max_right) = maxmin4(vetor,(fim-inicio)/2 + inicio,fim)
        if (max_left < max_right):
            max = max_right
        else:
            max = max_left
        if (min_left < min_right):
            min = min_left
        else:
            min = min_right
    return (min,max)
```

and the results:

```
input N     time algorithm 1 |  time algorithm 2
1000000 |   0.1299650669     |  0.6347620487 
2000000 |   0.266600132      |  1.3034451008
3000000 |   0.393116951      |  2.2436430454
4000000 |   0.5371210575     |  2.5098109245
5000000 |   0.6094739437     |  3.4496300221
6000000 |   0.8271648884     |  4.6163318157
7000000 |   1.0598180294     |  4.8950240612 
8000000 |   1.053456068      |  5.1900761128
9000000 |   1.1843969822     |  5.6422820091
10000000|   1.361964941      |  6.9290060997
```

I don't understand why the first algorithm was faster than the second, since the first have the complexity 2(n -1) and the second have complexity 3n/2 -2 and in theory the first is slower than the second. why it happens?

Comment: what is fim and inicio

Comment: @ShivamShah: Sounds like either last or order, and first, in some Romance language. Maybe Portuguese or Romanian?

Comment: fim is end 
and inicio is begin. It's the begin and the end of the array.

Comment: If you're trying to test for differences in algorithmic complexity, testing 100K, 200K, …, 1000K isn't very helpful. Try 100, 1000, 10000, … 1000K.

Comment: Meanwhile, if you're trying to optimize a linear algorithm by reducing the number of comparisons, by using an `elif` instead of a second `if` in `minmax1`, you can cut them in half, with no added cost. But all that will prove is that the comparisons aren't actually your real cost here, because the improvement is less than 1%; a loop iteration or function call takes much, much longer than a float comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be very surprised to *ever* see Python recursion run faster then Python iteration. Try this implementation of maxmin, taking two values at a time.

```
def minmax(seq):

    def byTwos(seq):
        # yield values from sequence two at a time
        # if an odd number of values, just return
        # the last value twice (won't hurt minmax
        # evaluation)
        seq = iter(seq)
        while 1:
            last = next(seq)
            yield last,next(seq,last)

    seqByTwos = byTwos(seq)
    # initialize minval and maxval
    a,b = next(seqByTwos,(None,None))
    if a < b:
        minval,maxval = a,b
    else:
        minval,maxval = b,a

    # now walk the rest of the sequence
    for a,b in seqByTwos:
        if a < b:
            if a < minval:
                minval = a
            if b > maxval:
                maxval = b
        else:
            if b < minval:
                minval = b
            if a > maxval:
                maxval = a
    return minval, maxval
```

If you want to count comparisons, then pass a sequence of objects that implement `__lt__` and `__gt__`, and have those methods update a global counter.

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out, there does seem to be a bug in your code or a mistake in your analysis—but it doesn't matter. I'll get to it at the end.

If you look at your results, it seems pretty clear that there's a constant difference of about 5x between the two. That implies that the algorithmic complexity of the second isn't any worse than the first, it's just got a much higher constant multiplier—you're doing the same number of steps, but each one is much more work.

---

It's possible that this is just an artifact of you testing such a narrow range, only a single factor of 10. But running your tests with a wider range of values, like this:

```
for i in 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000:
    v = [random.random() for _ in range(i)]
    t1 = timeit.timeit(lambda: maxmin1(v), number=1)
    t2 = timeit.timeit(lambda: maxmin4(v, 0, len(v)), number=1)
    print('{:8}: {:.8f} {:.8f} (x{:.8f})'.format(i, t1, t2, t2/t1))
```

… you can see that the pattern holds up:

```
     100: 0.00002003 0.00010014 (x5.00000000)
    1000: 0.00017500 0.00080800 (x4.61716621)
   10000: 0.00172400 0.00821304 (x4.76393307)
  100000: 0.01630187 0.08839488 (x5.42237660)
 1000000: 0.17010999 0.76053309 (x4.47083153)
10000000: 1.77093697 8.32503319 (x4.70092010)
```

---

So, why the higher constant overhead in the second version? Well, the first version is just doing a simple `for` iteration, two comparisons, and 1 assignment for each element. The second is calling functions, building and exploding tuples, doing more comparisons, etc. That's bound to be slower. If you want to know why it's exactly 5x slower (or, actually, 15x slower, if you're doing 2n/3 steps instead of just 2n), you'll need to do some profiling, or at least look at the bytecode. But I don't think it's worth it.

---

The moral of the story is that there's a reason 2(n-1) and 2n/3-2 are both O(n): When you've got two different complexity classes, like O(n) and O(n**2), that will always make a difference for large n; when you've got two algorithms in the same class, the constants in the implementation (the cost of each step) can easily outweigh the constants in the step count.

---

Meanwhile, how can we verify the 2n/3-2 analysis? Simple, just add a global counter that you increment once for each call to maxmin4. Here are the expected and actual results:

```
     100:         65        127
    1000:        665       1023
   10000:       6665      11807
  100000:      66665     131071
 1000000:     666665    1048575
10000000:    6666665   11611391
```

But this just means you're doing about 2/3rds as many steps instead of about 1/3rd, so the constant cost of each steps is 7.5x rather than 15x. In the end, that doesn't really affect the analysis.

Answer (score 3):

Although the divide and conquer approach guarantees the minimum number of compares, the actual complexity of the program depends on the total number of operations performed in the program.

In your case, you do around 4 or 5 operations for about n/2 function calls ( leaf nodes of the binary tree of the function calls), and around 16 operations for the internal nodes ( counting all the assignments, arithmetic operations, comparisons,and tuple constructions). That sums up to around 10n total operations.

In the first program, the total number of operations are essentially 2.x*n (where x depends on the number of assignments performed) .

This, together with the relative simplicity of operations in program 1 over program 2 results in the factor of 5 observed in the two programs.

Also, the number of compares by the divide and conquer algorithm should be 3n/2, and not 2n/3.

Comment: you're right, the number of compares by the divide and conquer is 3n/2 , I wrote wrong. I will repair this.